# How can I get the Python module termios to work in Cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, termios, urwid

I want to run [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/) in Windows so I downloaded and installed Cygwin (default packages only). I tried the Hello World example:

```
import urwid

txt = urwid.Text(u"Hello World")
fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')
loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill)
loop.run()
```

but it complains about `termios`:

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urwid
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urwid-1.1.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\urwid\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from urwid.graphics import (BigText, LineBox, BarGraphMeta, BarGraphError,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urwid-1.1.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\urwid\graphics.py", line 30, in <module>
    from urwid.display_common import AttrSpec
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urwid-1.1.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\urwid\display_common.py", line 23, in <module>
    import termios
ImportError: No module named termios
```

I went back to the installer and installed all packages matching `term` as search term, but I still get the same error.

Please, all you Cygwin deities out there, could you assist a feeble noob in sorting this annoying issue out?

EDIT: I am running Python 2.7.2 on Windows 7 if that matters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After installing the actual `Python` packages and `libmpfr4` that was also missing everything worked just fine...

Comment: What python packages did you install? I have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36508126/importerror-no-module-named-termios-with-django-mysql-on-windows

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could mention which packages. Thanks