# ImportError: No module named termios with django_mysql on Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, windows64, django-mysql

I'm on a 64bit `Windows` machine working on a `Django` project using `PyCharm`. Django 1.8.7, Python 2.7.9, MySQL 5.6. I'd like to try out `django_mysql`, but I get:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x03F8AE90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 551, in __call__
    return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django_mysql\apps.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .checks import register_checks
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django_mysql\checks.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django_mysql.utils import collapse_spaces
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\lib\site-packages\django_mysql\utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pty
  File "c:\python27\Lib\pty.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tty
  File "c:\python27\Lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
    from termios import *
ImportError: No module named termios
```

I installed `Cygwin`, which seemed to help people with similar issues, but I still get this error. I restarted `PyCharm`. Should I restart the machine? Am I `missing` some application form the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

My purpose with `django_mysql` is to use `JSONField`, maybe I should try another package?

Comment: Did you try using environment variable?

Comment: No. I assumed CYGWIN sets env vars during the install process. What env vars should I set?

Comment: Looks like it didn't set any environment variables. Do you know what to set?

Comment: Well, I was just guessing and added the Cygwin's bin folder to Windows's PATH. Restarted PyCharm. No luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

library author here. Turns out `pty` doesn't exist on Windows Python distributions. I've deployed a new Django-MySQL version, 1.0.8, to deal with this. See https://github.com/adamchainz/django-mysql/issues/272